# env.is_feature_activated unresolvable while setting up eosio.system contract

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, eosio.system, contract-development

I am following [`BIOS Boot Sequence`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence). I want to set up my own private EOS network that's why I am setting up the EOSIO network. at [`step 1.12`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence#section--1-12-set-the-eosio-system-contract-) I am not able to set the eosio.system contract it will give me error of **env.is_feature_activated unresolvable**

I am using ubuntu 18.04 with 4CPUs, 16GB RAM, 30GB HDD configuration.
also, EOSIO v1.8.1, EOSIO.CDT v1.6.0, EOSIO.CONTRACT v1.7.0 so in that I am facing two issues currently,

First: ./build.sh script won't be completed successfully though, it reaches too 100%, at last, it 'll give me an error (PFA)
[image]
so, in this when I run the `./build.sh` script all contracts would be compiled successfully but at last, it'll give me an error of **" recipe for target 'all' failed "**

Second: when I thought to avoid this error and decide to move further so `step 1.9 to step 1.11` will go smooth but `step 1.12` I'll face this error (PFA)
[image]

I tried with many EOSIO, EOSIO.CDT, EOSIO.CONTRACT versions but the issue remain the same.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to our community. I just want to ask you to don't use screenshots for error messages, because they are not searchable.

Comment: Okay. I'll take care of it. Thanks